# Javascript .onload and .onerror alternative way

Tags: javascript, onload, onerror

I have this peace of JS code:

```
// url = some url that return 200 or 403/404 status code

function f1() {

  let script = document.createElement('script')

  script.src = url; 
  
  script.onload = () => console.log("onload triggered");
  script.onerror = () => console.log("onerror triggered");
  document.head.appendChild(script)
}

f1();
```

I need an alternative way to trigger load and error events with no `.onload` and `.onerror` strings.
Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Soviut I have tried this solution. But the server is filtering some strings like .onload and .onerror. I tried with eval(atob(.....base64_code....)) but also eval is filtered. so I am writing here because I would like to know if there is an alternative way. I am not a web developer.

Comment: Have you tried `addEventListener`?